# Sort by column name that I don't want in the resultset

Tags: sql

```
SELECT city, state
FROM 
(
select * 
from sales.customers
order by zip_code
) t
```

Executing this code give me the following error:
*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.*

I want to sort my result by zip_code but don't want them to be printed, so I tried using subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make your selection in your principal query like this:

```
SELECT city, state
from sales.customers
order by zip_code
```